# android layout: This tag and its children can be replaced by one and a compound drawable

Tags: java, android-studio, drawable, android-drawable

When I run layout on a specific XML file, I get this:

This tag and its children can be replaced by one  and a compound drawable  A LinearLayout which contains an ImageView and a TextView can be more efficiently handled as a compound drawable (a single TextView, using the drawableTop, drawableLeft, drawableRight and/or drawableBottom attributes to draw one or more images adjacent to the text).  If the two widgets are offset from each other with margins, this can be replaced with a drawablePadding attribute.  There's a lint quickfix to perform this conversion in the Eclipse plugin.  Issue id: UseCompoundDrawables

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/todo"
        android:src="@drawable/logo" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textSlogan"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/slogan"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"></TextView>

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:weightSum="2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <info.hoang8f.widget.FButton
        android:id="@+id/btnSignUp"
        android:text="@string/signup"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:buttonColor="@color/btnSignUp"
        app:shadowColor="@android:color/black"
        app:shadowEnabled="true"
        app:shadowHeight="5dp"
        app:cornerRadius="4dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: What is your actual question?

Comment: i have a problem with the text view

Answer (score 0):

If you putting ImageView beside TextView it's recommended to replace the ImageView with of these TextView Attributes (drawableTop, drawableLeft, drawableRight and/or drawableBottom)
In your case you can replace this

```
    <ImageView
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:contentDescription="@string/todo"
    android:src="@drawable/logo" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textSlogan"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="@string/slogan"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"></TextView>
```

with this

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textSlogan"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="@string/slogan"
    app:drawableStartCompat="@drawable/logo"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"/>
```